# How I determine the surface area and the x-coordinate of the hub?

Tags: calculus, integration

How I determine the surface area of  $D=\{ (x,y) \mid x\ge 0,\ 0\le y\le {16}-{25}x^2 \}$ and the x-coordinate of the hub?

$\bar{x}=\frac{1}{A}\iint_D x\, \mathrm{d}A.$

Comment: Hi & welcome to MSE. To help give you a better answer which helps you the most, please provide some context, such as where the problem comes from, what you've tried so far already (and, especially, had difficulty with), etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the bounds of x: set $y = 0$

$ 0 = 16 - 25x^2 $

$ x = \pm \frac{4}{5} $

Since, $ x \geq 0, x = \frac{4}{5} $

The new equation would formulate to be. 
 $$ \bar{x} = \frac{15}{128}\int\limits_{0}^{16} \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{4}{5}} x dxdy $$